# Resources failed to load when X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Tags: security, iis, coldfusion, same-origin-policy

I have a website built in coldfusion.For security purpose I added `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` in IIS settings. After that, all resources like css, js and images failed to load in the website.

My website url is like :

> https://example.com/foldera/index.cfm?fuseaction=reports.home

I inspected the image url for example it shows the url as `images/logo.png` and when open in new tab it shows full path as

> https://example.com/foldera/images/logo.png

Initially, I thought it is because I use relative url, but I tried with absolute url also. It didn't work. Can anyone suggest what is going wrong here? I am not using any iframes

Comment: The `X-Frame-Options` response header is used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>` or `<object>`. Are you saying that your assets are not loading even when the page is NOT being loaded via one of those methods?